# Per page items not working in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, pagination

The "Per page" items dropdown in my magento website is not working at all. The default value is set to 12 items (list includes 12,24,36) , but loads all products by default. When i select 24, the page loads to the following url

```
'/accessories?limit=24'
```

but still loads all the products and no pagination appears. Could someone please point me in the right direction to fix this problem!

**EDIT**

The "Sort by" field is working. Only the Items per page is not.

Comment: Do you have any custom code related to the product listing? Make sure the collection is not loaded before it is passed to the pager block

Comment: @Marius I'm sorry, i'm quite new to magento , this is happening in the category list page. So no other modules are being loaded here. just the menu and the listing page. How can i check if the collection is being loaded?

Comment: Try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Comment: Please make a screenshot of the settings and provide it here and the link to your webshop, this will contribute towards helping you with your problem.

Comment: How many products are there?

Comment: @user6451  at the moment around 20 products

Comment: So all products coming when you have 12 selected? Check the drop down selected option

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something like that happen when people mix up Grid and List display modes. Basically if your Toolbar shows limits from List and you're trying to display Grid AND your chosen limit is not among Grid available limits, default is used. It happens usually with heavily modified category pages where one or another display method has been removed.

Comment: The layout has been edited (just basic styles) , but the list and grid values are not switched like you say.